# React component. Not showing the correct value after loading contents

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am using react to show some text in a component like this in the context of a fetch API call inside a class. The call to loadContents does the following:

- Get the raw html.
- replace an html element by a React component showing some text that was placed in the original html and showing this component with the rest of the original html.

The problem I get is that the text is correctly retrieved in the variable `myText` but not correctly shown in the React component afterwards:

```
handleClickLink(event) {
    const simpleHttpRegex = new RegExp(`https?://[a-zA-z0-9:_.]+\(/.*)`);
    var match = simpleHttpRegex.exec(event.target.href);
    if (match != null) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.preventDefault();
        this.loadContents(match[1], true);
    }
    else {
        console.log('Regular expression did not match url');
    }
}



loadContents() {
fetch(url,
      ...).then(response => response.text())
            .then((responseBody) => {
                this.state.myTexts = [];
                const parser = new DOMParser();
                const dom = parser.parseFromString(responseBody, "text/html");
                const content = dom.getElementById('content');
                let preTags = Array.from(content.getElementsByTagName('pre'));
                preTags.forEach(
                    (v) => {
                        if (v.classList.contains('someclass')) {
                            this.state.myTexts.push(v.innerText);
                        }
                    }, this);
                const serializedContent = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(content);
                let i = 0;
                const replaceDivs = (node, index) => {     
                    if (node.type === 'tag' && node.name == 'div'
                             && ('class' in node.attribs) &&
                             node.attribs['class'] === 'someclass2') {
                        const myText = this.state.myTexts[i];
                        i++;
                        return <ReactComp key={'comp' + i.toString()} text={myText}/>;
                    }
                    return undefined;
                };
          const componentFromResponse = 
                 ReactHtmlParser(serializedContent, {transform: 
                  replaceDivs});
            this.setState({pageContents: componentFromResponse});
}
```

1. calling `loadContents('/contents1')` downloads the html resource and makes the replacement when pressing the link through `handleClick`.
2. The same is true for `loadContents('/contents2')`: download the html resource and make the replacement when pressing the link through `handleClick`.

The ReactComp is showing forever "someTextPage1" if I load first /contents1 even if I load later /contents2. The same happens if I start through /contents2: "someTextPage2" will be loaded into the ReactComponent and never changed. The rest of the contents are loaded correctly when I press the links, it is just the React component the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the problem is that not new Component is constructed if the key attribute matches a previous one even if the contents loaded are different. The `ReactComp` is reused. So this code:

```
return <ReactComp key={'comp' + i.toString()} text={myText}/>;
```

when two pages are loaded but the key matches, does not create a new instance of ReactComp, but reuses it insted. The solution is to use in `ReactComp` the following:

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
    if (prevState.text != nextProps.text) {
        return {value : nextProps.text};
    }
    return null;
}
```

That will refresh the existing component with the property changes when no new instance is created.